# Apollo server context initialization function parameter?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

In Apollo server [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/), Apollo server constructor  run with some configurations, one of them is a context  initialization function  that is called with every request, and according to the docs, this function parameter is an object that get the request (`req`) automatically as one field of that object.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    authScope: getScope(req.headers.authorization)
  }),
});
```

This is ok for me, but in one project i got from [Github](https://github.com/Urigo/WhatsApp-Clone-Server/blob/master/server.ts) that creates a what's app clone, the parameter object is different which i couldn't relate, something i searched for and i couldn't find anything can relate

```
export const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: rootModule.schema,
  context: (session: any) => {
    if (session.connection) {
      const req = session.connection.context.session.request;
      const cookies = req.headers.cookie;

      if (cookies) {
        req.cookies = cookie.parse(cookies);
      }
    }

    return rootModule.context(session);
  },
});
```

The context function parameter is a session object, and the developer need to get the request from that session object using that verbose code:

```
 const req = session.connection.context.session.request;
```

I searched about that session parameter but couldn't find anything in the docs or anywhere else

I am confused about this inconsistency, **or am i missing something**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the actual context object can change dependending on the apollo server configuration (see: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/api/apollo-server#middleware-specific-context-fields)

My guess in the "WhatsApp-clone", the parameter comes from the subscription support of Apollo Server (here as in the github repo from Version 2):  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/data/subscriptions/#operation-context

For whatever reason the argument in the example project is called `session` it is propably that object described in the documentation.

The subscription support is added here to the example server: https://github.com/Urigo/WhatsApp-Clone-Server/blob/master/index.ts#L13